# Monitor the list for changes

Tags: list-manipulation

I wrote a function to monitor the list of variable. What it does is if the variable in list change, the changed variable will be separated from others. check the function and output

```
ListMo[monitorList_, OptionsPattern[]] :=
(
 Module[{il = {}},

 (
    If[
        (UnsameQ[monitorList, Global`temp]),
        (
    il = {Complement[monitorList, Global`temp], 
    Intersection[monitorList, Global`temp]};
    Global`temp = monitorList;
    il
    )
    ]
    )
 ])
```

I initialize temp variable separately

```
temp = {"Value1", "Value2", "Value3", "Value4"};
```

I call the function

```
monitorList1 = {"Value1", "Value2", "Value3", "Value4"};
ListMo[monitorList1]
```

Output will be nothing

If I change value in monitorList1 like

```
monitorList1 = {"Graphs", "Value2", "Value3", "Value4"};
```

The output should be

```
{{"Graphs"},{"Value2", "Value3", "Value4"}}
```

again If I change in monitorList1 like

```
 monitorList1 = {"Graphs", "Value2", "Value3", "computer"};
```

The output should be

```
{{"computer"},{"Graphs","Value2", "Value3"}}
```

Here am getting output, But I want them to be `Dynamic`. If I put `Dynamic` around `ListMo[monitorList1]` like `Dynamic[ListMo[monitorList1]]` the output is keep on executing instead of executing one time. I used `TrackedSymbole` as `Dynamic[ListMo[monitorList1], TrackedSymbols -> monitorList1]` but no use.

I used `StartScheduledTask[]` as well like

```
Module[
        {testing = {}},
        StartScheduledTask[
           CreateScheduledTask[
             With[{testing1 = {}}, testing = ListMo[monitorList1];]
           ]
        ];
        Dynamic[testing]
    ]
```

but it doesn't help.
Help me to write better code for same concept.

Comment: There are (undocumented) ways to do this, which I don't have time to go into now. I'm concerned though that the (highly unusual) requirement for this mechanism might suggest, more than anything else, that your program design could be improved.

Answer (score 2):

Something along these lines?

```
SetAttributes[ListMo, HoldFirst];
ListMo[l_] := DynamicModule[{last = l, curr = l},
  Dynamic[
   last = curr;
   curr = l;
   {Complement[l, last], Intersection[l, last]},
   TrackedSymbols:>{l}
   ]
  ]
```

So

```
list = Range@4;
ListMo[list]
```

and now

```
list[[2]] = 20;
```